# aws sdk ec2.describeInstances not listing all EC2 instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm using [aws-sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstances-property) to list all the running EC2 instances whose IAM Role is `The_Name_of_My_IAM_Role`.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

let credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({
  profile: 'my_profile'
})
AWS.config.credentials = credentials
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'ap-northeast-1'
})

const ec2 = new AWS.EC2()

let params = {
  Filters: [
    {
      Name: 'iam-instance-profile.arn',
      Values: [`arn:aws:iam::123456789123:instance-profile/The_Name_of_My_IAM_Role`]
    },
    {
      Name: 'instance-state-name',
      Values: ['running']
    }
  ]
}
ec2.describeInstances(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`describeInstances error: ${err}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`data.Reservations.length: ${data.Reservations.length}`)
  }
})
```

I expect the code to return 6 EC2 instances. But it returns only 4 of them.

The problem doesn't occur if I type `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=iam-instance-profile.arn,Values=arn:aws:iam::123456789123:instance-profile/The_Name_of_IAM_Role" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"` command in my terminal.

I mean `aws ec2 describe-instances ...` command returns all 6 EC2 instances.

I've set the following environment variables before running `aws ec2 describe-instances ...` command.

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-northeast-1
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=my_profile
```

I also have `my_profile` defined in `~/.aws/credentials` file.

What might be wrong my node.js code?

Or is this a bug of `aws-sdk`?

Comment: Are the 4 that *are* returned part of the 6 returned from the CLI? (That is, are they the *same* instances?) If you remove the filters, do the results contain (at a minimum) the 6 instances you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that Reservations contain Instances.

When multiple instances are launched via one command (eg launching two identical instances in the console), then both instances are part of a single Reservation.

Your code is counting the number of Reservations, but you are actually expecting the count to include the number of instances in all Reservations.

**Solution:** Loop through the reservations and add up the number of instances in each Reservation.

Comment: You are right. I found that 2 instances are included in a reservation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell script (using **aws-cli**) to loop through all regions and display all ec2 instances within a table:

```
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[*].RegionName' --output text); do
   echo "Region: $region"
   aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{name: Tags[?Key=='Name'] | [0].Value, instance_id: InstanceId, ip_address: PrivateIpAddress, state: State.Name}" --output table
done
```

there should be the same methods for node.js